# Queue multiple system() commands using C++

Tags: c++, linux, unix, fork, system

I have a program that I need to execute 100 times with different arguments each time, using my 10 processors.

So basically I want to do multiple system calls, in order to finish my list. However if I just put system() in a for loop, it will use only one processor and it will go one by one.
How can I open multiple terminals, that can run different programs at the same time, and at the end report that they finished, enabling me to assign to that specific processor a new task from the pool?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could make a single system call to GNU parallel, asking it to coordinate the concurrent work?  See [man page here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

Comment: You want to queue the processes, *and* run them at the same time?

Comment: My jobs are more than my processors, so I want to run as many as my processors jobs in parallel keeping just in a pool the rest of them.

Comment: Do you really want to do this using C++? As @TonyD says GNU parallel might be a good option, or you could use a perl script - I have had success using [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) to do this kind of thing

Answer (score 3):

You should read about the `fork`, `exec` and `wait` system calls.

In principle you do a `fork`/`exec` combination for each subprocess and record its PID. When you have all the processes running you want, use `wait` or a variant to wait for completion. You can then deal with return values, starting another process, etc.

Comment: And also the related `waitpid` syscall. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/): it has several chapters on that subject. And you probably should avoid forking hundreds of processes at once (only dozens at most).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `popen()` instead. system() is not a good option for this. You can open as many streams as you like (within reason) and communicate with each of the processes independently). popen() wraps fork + pipe + exec and the processes will be scheduled by the OS, independent of your parent process.

Or consider implementing your own using fork / exec. You can use waitpid, etc. to check the status of idividual PIDs to know their exit code, although I like using popen() with richer feedback by parsing a text return message from the program.

Comment: "downside to popen is reaping the child exit status, you cant" - have you seen some problem getting it during the `pclose` call?

Comment: @TonyD - Well honestly I did't remember any problem about pclose(), usually if I'm using popen() its because I am interacting with the process textually, and then when I'm done I pclose() and fire and forget. But when I checked the man page a few moments ago for the error code before answering, I misread the doc and thought it said ` pclose() cannot obtain the child status` when it says `If pclose() cannot...' so not thinking I just repeated it. I'll be honest, in spite of misreading that, I don't recall ever knowing pclose() returned the exit status, always assumed it was a FILE abstraction.

Comment: I corrected my answer (@TonyD pointed out my error). I guess the truth is on this side of 40, I'm starting to forget what I knew...or if I even knew it, I don't remember now... :D

Comment: Me too mate, me too... ;-.